# Finding a moment generating function for a continuous random variable defined by its pdf.

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, moment-generating-functions

The pdf of a continuous random variable $X$ is defined by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac1{10} (5-2x)&,\text{ if } x \in [0,2)
\\ \frac1{10}(x-1)&,\text{ if } x \in [2,4]
\\  0 &,\text{ otherwise } 
\end{cases}
$$

Find the moment generating function (mgf) $M_X(t)$ of $X$.

I know that $M_X(t)$ is found through the improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}f_X(x)\,dx$, but I do not know how to fill $f_X(x)$ in this integral.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math.

Comment: You are given the pdf $f_X()$ which is just $f()$ here. What do you mean you 'do not know how to fill'?

Comment: You can split the interval into $$\int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{tx}f(x)dx + \int_{0}^{2} e^{tx}f(x)dx + \int_{2}^{4} e^{tx}f(x)dx + \int_{4}^{\infty} e^{tx}f(x)dx$$

Comment: I just want to know how to find mgf. What I mean is, I do not know how to use the two intervals to calculate mgf. I really would appreciate your help.

Comment: @WestonMiller This does not give me the mgf, does it?

Comment: @StubbornAtom thank you for editing my question. I did not know how to do it. I will use MathJax in the future.

Comment: @KCK it should give the mgf, unless I am mistaken. I have not taken a formal probability course—only done self-study through textbooks.

Comment: @KCK The integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx} f(x)\,dx$ is the mgf, right? The integral split has been shown above. Why do you doubt if it is the mgf or not?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{tx}f(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{o}e^{tx}f(x)dx + \int_{0}^{2}e^{tx}f(x)dx + \int_{2}^{4}e^{tx}f(x)dx + \int_{4}^{+\infty}e^{tx}f(x)dx = $$

$$\int_{0}^{2}e^{tx}f(x)dx + \int_{2}^{4}e^{tx}f(x)dx = \int_0^2 e^{tx}\frac{1}{10}(5-2x)dx +  \int_2^4 e^{tx}\frac{1}{10}(x-1)dx = $$

$$\frac{1}{10}\left(\int_0^2 e^{tx}(5-2x)dx +  \int_2^4 e^{tx}(x-1)dx\right) = \frac{1}{10}\left(\int_0^2 \frac{1}{t}(5-2x)de^{tx} +  \int_2^4 \frac{1}{t}(x-1)de^{tx}\right) = $$

$$\frac{1}{10t}\left(\int_0^2 (5-2x)de^{tx} +  \int_2^4 (x-1)de^{tx}\right) = \frac{1}{10t}(5-2x)e^{tx}|_0^2 + \frac{1}{10t}(x-1)e^{tx}|_2^4 - \frac{1}{10t}\left(\int_0^2 e^{tx}d(5-2x) +  \int_2^4 e^{tx}d(x-1)\right) = $$

$$ \frac{1}{10t}(5-2x)e^{tx}|_0^2 +  \frac{1}{10t}(x-1)e^{tx}|_2^4 - \frac{1}{10t}\left(\int_0^2 -2e^{tx}dx +  \int_2^4 e^{tx}dx\right)$$

Can you cantinue from here?

Comment: How did you get de^tx? It looks quite complicated to me. Do you know if there is any simpler way to find the mgf. Maybe there is some kind of definition or so. I do not know if the formula for the linear transformation is applicable. (aX+b)

Comment: @KCK Its integration by parts, Calculus I. I don't think there exists simpler method to do this